# Pagination for php flickr-search results

Tags: php, pagination, flickr

I made a Flickr search using their API. How should I proceed (what are the steps) to make results show with pagination?

> $Flickr is my own class
>
> search() -> searches for the query, and
>
> getImages() -> returns an array of strings (the links for the images).

search.php :

```
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php

  $query = $_GET['query'];
  $Flickr = new Flickr;

  $pageNumber = 1;
  $Flickr->search($query,$pageNumber);
  $imagesLinks = $Flickr->getImages();

  foreach($imagesLinks as $imageSRC){
    echo '<li><img src='. $imageSRC .' class="imagelightbox"></li>';
  }
?>

</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: having the same id for multiple elements would be invalid HTML

Comment: Corrected that, sorry.

Comment: does this 'Flickr' class have a `getPageCount` method? or `getImageCount` method? because you'll need one of those to do pagination